# Trouble with setting file mode in SMBJ

Tags: java, linux, smb, amazon-fsx, smbj

I'm trying to set the file mode of a remote located file in a SMB share though SMBJ library. But I get STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER error.

This is my code snippet:

```java
Set<FileAttributes> fileAttributes = new HashSet<(Arrays.asList(FileAttributes.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY));
Set<SMB2CreateOptions> createOptions = new HashSet<>();
createOptions.add(SMB2CreateOptions.FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE);
File f = share.openFile("folder01/abc.sh", new HashSet<(Collections.singletonList(AccessMask.GENERIC_ALL)), fileAttributes, SMB2ShareAccess.ALL, SMB2CreateDisposition.FILE_OPEN_IF, createOptions);
f.setFileInformation(new FileModeInformation(755));
```

And this is the stack trace I'm seeing

```
com.hierynomus.mssmb2.SMBApiException: STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER (0xc000000d): SetInfo failed for SMB2FileId{persistentHandle=f2 29 00 00 01 00 00 01}
    at com.hierynomus.smbj.share.Share.receive(Share.java:380)
    at com.hierynomus.smbj.share.Share.sendReceive(Share.java:359)
    at com.hierynomus.smbj.share.Share.setInfo(Share.java:191)
    at com.hierynomus.smbj.share.DiskShare.setFileInformation(DiskShare.java:330)
    at com.hierynomus.smbj.share.DiskEntry.setFileInformation(DiskEntry.java:89)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DiskShare share = getSmbSession();
        Set<SMB2ShareAccess> shareAccessSet = new HashSet();
        shareAccessSet.add(SMB2ShareAccess.FILE_SHARE_READ);
        shareAccessSet.add(SMB2ShareAccess.FILE_SHARE_WRITE);
        shareAccessSet.add(SMB2ShareAccess.FILE_SHARE_DELETE);
        Set<FileAttributes> fileAttributes = new HashSet();
        fileAttributes.add(FileAttributes.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL);
        Set<SMB2CreateOptions> createOptions = new HashSet();
        SMB2CreateDisposition smb2CreateDisposition = SMB2CreateDisposition.FILE_OPEN_IF;
        createOptions.add(SMB2CreateOptions.FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE);
        smb2CreateDisposition = SMB2CreateDisposition.FILE_OPEN_IF;
        Directory directory = share.openDirectory(pathFrom, EnumSet.of(AccessMask.MAXIMUM_ALLOWED), fileAttributes,
                shareAccessSet, smb2CreateDisposition, createOptions);
```